# JPA @JoinTable do not create foreign keys in phpmyadmin

Tags: hibernate, jpa, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, join

I am new to Hibernate and JPA.
I would like to create a **@ManyToMany** relationship between the Movie 
and Actor class.

In the *hibernate.cfg.xml* file, I have set the following configuration:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Here a code snapshot from the **Movie** and **Actor** entities.

```
@Entity
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    private Long movie_id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
        name="Movie_Actor",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="movie_id")},
        foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_movie"),
        inverseForeignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_actor"),
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="actor_id")}
    )
    private Set<Actor> actors = new HashSet<Actor>();

    //default constructor, set & get methods, toString, hashCode, equals
}

@Entity
public class Actor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    private Long actor_id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="actors")
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<Movie>();

    //default constructor, set & get methods, toString, hashCode, equals
}
```

Here below I reported the SQL debug:

```
create table Actor (actor_id bigint not null auto_increment, age integer, name varchar(255) not null, surname varchar(255) not null, primary key (actor_id)) engine=MyISAM
create table Movie (movie_id bigint not null auto_increment, title varchar(255) not null, primary key (movie_id)) engine=MyISAM
create table Movie_Actor (movie_id bigint not null, actor_id bigint not null, primary key (movie_id, actor_id)) engine=MyISAM
alter table Actor drop index uk_name_surname
alter table Actor add constraint uk_name_surname unique (name, surname)
alter table Movie drop index UK_s9ecovryb6e6xo86rh5ddjiyi
alter table Movie add constraint UK_s9ecovryb6e6xo86rh5ddjiyi unique (title)
alter table Movie_Actor add constraint fk_actor foreign key (actor_id) references Actor (actor_id)
alter table Movie_Actor add constraint fk_movie foreign key (movie_id) references Movie (movie_id)
```

As you can see, seems that the foreign keys **"fk_actor"** and **"fk_movie"** are correctly created, but then when I see the result on **phpmyadmin**, this is what I have in the Movie_Actor table structure:

[image: Movie_Actor table structure]

That is, only **"fk_actor"** key was created.
And looking at the Movie_Actor table data, here what I have:

[image: Movie_Actor table data]

The data are **NOT blue**, i.e. there is not a link (foreign key) associated with them. When instead I add manually the relationship between the two tables I have the result I am looking for:

[image: Movie_Actor table data after creating manual relationship]

**How can I obtain the same result without doing the manual operation?

I am doing something wrong? What am I missing?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that table engine=MyISAM doesn't create foreign key constraints. I had to change the engine to INNODB.
In Java hibernate, the following property changes the engine type to InnoDB

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
#or
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
```